# PHP preg_replace Expertise Sought

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace

I'm creating some custom BBcode for a forum.  I'm trying to get the regular expression right, but it has been eluding me for two days.  Any expert advice is welcome.

The input (e.g. sample forum post):

> [quote=Bob]I like Candace. She is nice.[/quote]
>
> I agree, she is very nice. I like Ashley, too, and especially [Ryan] when he's drinking.

Essentially, I want to encase any names (from a specified list) in [user][/user] BBcode... except, of course, those being quoted, because doing that causes some terrible parsing errors. Below is an example of how I want the output to be.

The desired output:

> [quote=Bob]I like [user]Candace[/user]. She is nice.[/quote]
>
> I agree, she is very nice. I like [user]Ashley[/user], too, and especially [[user]Ryan[/user]] when he's drinking.

My current code:

```
$searchArray = array(
  '/(?i)(Ashley|Bob|Candace|Ryan|Tim)/'
);

$replaceArray = array(
  "[user]\\0[/user]"
);

$text = preg_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $input);
```

$input is of course set to the post contents (i.e. the first example listed above).  How can I achieve the results I want?  I don't want the regex to match when a name is preceded by an equals sign (=), but putting a [^=] in front of the names in the regex will make it match any non-equals sign character (i.e. spaces), which then messes up the formatting.

**Update**

The problem is that by using \1 instead of \0 it is omitting the first character before the names (because anything but = is matched). The output results in this:

> [quote=Bob]I like[user]Candace[/user]. She is nice.[/quote]
>
> I agree, she is very nice. I like[user]Ashley[/user], too, and especially [user]Ryan[/user]] when he's drinking.

Comment: This would be a fairly simple fix if I could somehow modify the \\0 backreference with things like the PHP function substr, but if I set a variable to \\0 and then substitute that variable in the replaceArray(), the callback isn't affected.  I suck at regex. :(

Comment: Are you looking for word boundaries? http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with the `[^=]` idea. You can put it outside the capture group, and instead of `\\0` which is the full match, use `\\1` and `\\2` i.e. the first & second capture groups

```
$searchArray = array(
  '/(?i)([^=])(Ashley|Bob|Candace|Ryan|Tim)/'
);

$replaceArray = array(
  "\\1[user]\\2[/user]"
);

$text = preg_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $input);
```